# Redis: sorting hash "fields" in alpha

Tags: sorting, hash, redis

I am trying to sort the "fields" in a hash.
For example,

1. mykey, cde, firstone
2. mykey, abcde, secondone
3. mykey, bcde, thirdone

I want to sort the fields(cde, abcde, bcde) in alphabet order, but there is no way to do so.. If anyone knows about this, please help me.

If there is no way to solve this, I am thinking about changing names of key&values.. and use zadd instead of hash. If you have a better solution, please give me an advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Hash field names are not sortable-by easily - there is no native command to do so and the order in which fields are returned (e.g. with `HGETALL`) is for all intents and purposes random.

While Sorted Sets are preferable when it comes to sorting, you could work around this with use of a Lua script that will perform lexical sorting the Hash's fields. For example:

```
$ cat hashsort.lua
local r = redis.call('HGETALL',KEYS[1])
local t = {}
for i=1,#r,2 do
    t[#t+1] = { field = r[i], value = r[i+1] }
end
table.sort(t, function(a,b) return a.field < b.field end)
r = {}
for _, v in pairs(t) do
    r[#r+1] = v.field
    r[#r+1] = v.value
end
return r

$ redis-cli HMSET hash z 99 ee 55 e 5 a 1 b 2 ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ justsomethinglongsohashmaxzipwillbeexceeded
OK
$ redis-cli --eval hashsort.lua hash
 1) "a"
 2) "1"
 3) "b"
 4) "2"
 5) "e"
 6) "5"
 7) "ee"
 8) "55"
 9) "z"
10) "99"
11) "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
12) "justsomethinglongsohashmaxzipwillbeexceeded"
```